# jenkins pipeline post actions not working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I setup a post action like in the examples:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example1') {
            steps {
                bat 'return 1'                    
            }
        stage('Example2') {
            steps {
                echo 'Wont see this'
            }
        }
    }
    post { 
        always { 
            echo 'I will always say Hello'
        }
    }
}
```

So I do something in the first stage to make it fail. And I have a post action that always runs, but what happens when I run my pipeline in blueocean is it fails at the first stage and then just stops. Where do I see the post action that is always supposed to run??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hade a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531003/how-to-use-post-steps-with-jenkins-pipeline-on-multiple-agents) when I used `agent none` at the beginning of the pipeline. Try using a `node` in your `post` action:

```
post {
    always {
        node('master') {
            echo 'I will always say Hello'
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Now I'm confused. Agent is descriptive node is scripted. So why does it have to be a scripted action and how does Jenkins treat it differently?

Comment: Good question, but I don't know the inner workings of Jenkins. I just noticed that specifying a `node` made my post action working.

Comment: If it's not working for you, why is it the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

Kind of late to the party but you have to use `catchError` before any steps that may fail. Something like this:

```
steps {
  catchError {
    bat 'return 1' 
  }             
}
```