# Is there any possible solution to run docker under post section (declarative pipeline) on Jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have try to run docker script to send test report to slack with script pipeline.
However, I don't have any clue how can we run docker script to send test report to slack with declarative pipeline script when branch is master

**Here is pipeline script what i have try**

```
def today = new Date()
def format = today.format('MM_dd_yyyy_HH_mm')

pipeline {
   agent {
        docker {
                            label 'master'
                            image 'postman/newman:latest'
                            args '--entrypoint=\'\' -u root:root'
        }
   }

    options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '2'))
    }
    stages {

         stage('Build')
         {
             steps{
                   sh "npm install -g newman-reporter-html"
                   sh "npm install -g newman-reporter-htmlextra"
             }
         }
 
    }
    post {
        always {
            script {
                if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master')
                {
                                     def currentResult = currentBuild.result == 'SUCCESS' ? 'success' : 'failure'
                                     withCredentials([string(credentialsId: '*****', variable: '****')]) {
                                     docker.image('mikewright/slack-client:latest')
                                         .run('-e SLACK_TOKEN=$TOKEN -e SLACK_CHANNEL=#devops_major_app',
                                             "\"${env.JOB_NAME}/${env.BRANCH_NAME} - Build#${env.BUILD_NUMBER}\n Status: ${currentResult}\n ${env.BUILD_URL}\"")
                                     }
                                     echo 'Already send slack message'
                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```

***Here is error on log***

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Major-mobileapp-test_master@tmp/durable-a70f07be/script.sh: line 1: docker: not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like my below example:

my `build` stage and post `always` use different docker build agent.

```
pipeline {
    agent none; // none is expected here because out goal is to use different build agent across
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'maven:3-alpine'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh "mvn -v"
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            script {
                docker.image('alpine').inside("-u 0:0") {
                    sh "apk update"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You was right !! . But Needed to be consider individual stage to set more specific, so that will match its purpose. Anyway, I am still consider that there is another solution which is set up your own docker that contain all images needed to run this pipeline then set up at agent only one time.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is in missing docker tool in docker image postman/newman:latest.

Because your case is about using docker in docker.

You could try to use 'agent' section to use another agent with installed docker tool in post step, try this as an example. [How to use post steps with Jenkins pipeline on multiple agents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531003/how-to-use-post-steps-with-jenkins-pipeline-on-multiple-agents)